# Skill stats are changing in a weird way

Tags: javascript, jquery

My problem: skill stats are changing in a weird way

1. They are changing in all fields not one.
2. The numbers are weird.
   Output is `1`, `111112` and `1.111121111121111e+35`, instead of `1, 2, 3, ...`

My js code:

```
var skillcount = 15;

// Dodawanie umiejętności

$('.skill-plus div img').click(function() {
    if (skillcount > 0) {
        var new_skillstat = parseInt($('td.skill-plus').closest('.skill-stat').text(),0) + 1;
        $('td.skill-plus').closest('.skill-stat').text(new_skillstat);
        $('.skill-item').val(new_skillstat);
        skillcount--;
        $('.abilities').text(skillcount);
        $('.register-abilities').val(skillcount);
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<?php
    $showSkills = $databasecon->getSome('*', 'skills', 'skill_cat', 0);
    while($showSkill = mysqli_fetch_array($showSkills)) {
?>
    <tr class="ability-record">
        <td><?php echo $showSkill['skill_name']; ?></td>
        <td class="skill-stat">0</td>
        <td class="skill-plus">
            <div class="stat-plus"><img src="images/plus.png" alt="Plus"></div>
            <td class="skill-minus">
                <div class="stat-minus"><img src="images/minus.png" alt="Minus"></div>
                <input type="hidden" name="skill-<?php echo $showSkill['id']; ?>" class="skill-item" value="0">
            </td>
        </td>
    </tr>

<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: How are zero-based numbers presented? Do such a number even exist? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt and specifically read about  `radix` parameter.

Comment: Code like `$('.abilities').text(skillcount);` will update _every_ element on the page with class `abilities` - you need to be a bit more exact with your element targetting.

Comment: (FYI: You've nested a `td` inside a `td`, this is prolly a typo)

Comment: 1. Changed the parseInt radix parameter to 10 and few others and it still works the same
2. the abilities class is only on one object (it shows the leftover skillpoints) so it's ok (that thing works)
3. thanks for letting me know about td thing

Comment: You've got the same problem however with `.skill-item` and `.skill-stat`. Inside that "click" handler, those selectors will still search the entire document and affect *all* matched elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit more complex than you thought

1. I delegate from the ability record
2. I do not allow to go negative on skill
3. Your HTML is invalid

```js
var skillcount = 15;

// Dodawanie umiejętności

$('.ability-record img').on('click', function() {
  const $row = $(this).closest('tr');
  const skillValue = $(this).closest('div').is('.stat-plus') ? 1 : -1
  let new_skillstat = +$row.find('.skill-stat').text() + skillValue;
  if (new_skillstat < 0) return; // negative
  $row.find('.skill-stat').text(new_skillstat);
  $row.find('.skill-item').val(new_skillstat);
  skillcount += skillValue * -1; // invert
  $('.abilities').text(skillcount);
  // $('.register-abilities').val(skillcount);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="ability-record">
      <td>
        Skill 1
      </td>
      <td class="skill-stat">0</td>
      <td class="skill-plus">
        <div class="stat-plus"><img src="images/plus.png" alt="Plus"></div>

        <div class="stat-minus"><img src="images/minus.png" alt="Minus"></div>
        <input type="hidden" name="skill-skill-1" class="skill-item" value="0" />
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="ability-record">
      <td>
        Skill 2
      </td>
      <td class="skill-stat">0</td>
      <td class="skill-plus">
        <div class="stat-plus"><img src="images/plus.png" alt="Plus"></div>
        <div class="stat-minus"><img src="images/minus.png" alt="Minus"></div>
        <input type="hidden" name="skill-skill-1" class="skill-item" value="0">
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
<span class="abilities"></span>
```

I wanted to stop when using too much skillCount but this did not work as I thought

```
const sum = $('.skill-stat')
.map(function() { return +this.textContent}) 
.get()
.reduce((a,b)=>a+b)
if (skillcount-sum <= 0) return; // negative
```

Comment: Works now, had to clear the cache of the browser sorry! :D